# Самого - это какое местоимение?

Tags: местоимения

Изучал, какие бывают местоимения: личные, возвратные, притяжательные... Не очень понятно, к каким из них относится "самого". Предложение вроде этого: "возвратное местоимение указывает, что действие направлено на самого деятеля" - здесь "самого", если мыслить по логике, употребляется для того, чтобы показать, что этот деятель не какой-нибудь, а чётко определённый, тот самый, который связан со словом "действие". Значит, это указательное местоимение? Или, если оно употребляется только в возвратных конструкциях (так ли это?), значит, это возвратное местоимение?

Comment: Тире можно получить удерживанием alt и нажатием 0151 (alt+0151)

Answer (score 1):

Это определительное местоимение, а точнее его падежная форма. Помню, как сам разбирался с этим вопросом некоторое время назад. Однако тут же хочу отметить, что есть и слово "сам", которое может быть не только местоимением (используется для таких же целей, кроме образования превосходной сравнительной степени), но и наречием:

**Он сделал это (как?) сам**.